# How to Regex match a "/" in C#

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I would like the "matched" bool to be true after executing this:

```
string urlSegment = "whatever('id')/"
string regexPattern = ?;
bool matched = Regex.Match(urlSegment, regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success
```

How do I escape the forward slash so I can have whatever followed by "('" followed by whatever id followed by "')/"? (something like regexPattern = "('*')/").

Comment: Whave you tried anything? Are you sure that you need to escape `/`and *did* you try to do that?

Comment: You can use `@"whatever\('id'\)/"` as the `regexPattern` to make the next statement true, but is it really how the url looks like?

Comment: Please post a different question instead of radically changing what you ask. Existing answers become meaningless otherwise. Worse, people that answered the original question won't notice that you asked a new question . The chances of getting a new question will suffer. Not my downvote but I'm tempted

Comment: Can you provide a couple examples of inputs and expected outputs? Is the ending slash required? If the input is `"whatever('id')/somethingelse('id2')/ do you want both ids? I'm thinking you may have over simplified your example and will get over simplified or overly specific answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the edit, here's my proposed pattern: `.+\('(.*)'\)/`

This will match any set of characters followed by parentheses and single quotes wrapping any set of characters. [RegexPal](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=93869)

---

Original answer:

There's no need to escape: [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eRa1Yn)

```
string urlSegment = "whatever('id')/";
string regexPattern = "/";
bool matched = Regex.Match(urlSegment, regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success;
```

Also this is a very simple match. A regex is a little overkill. You can just use `Contains()` to see if the string contains a second string. This is shown in the fiddle.

Comment: I don't think this is what OP actually wants, but then again this is correct. BTW, we might as well just use urlSegement.EndsWith("/").

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the `id` with like this :

```
string urlSegment = "whatever('id')/";
string regexPattern = @"whatever\('(?<id>.+)'\)/";

Match match = Regex.Match(urlSegment, regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
bool matched = match.Success;
string id = match.Groups["id"].Value;
```

Comment: @cFrozenDeath Probably best assumptions from a bad question.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath because the OP change the question text. Besides, sometimes there are patterns of bad questions, that experienced developers use to guess what someone really wants to ask. Similar to divining actual requirements from customer fancies

Comment: Didn't downvote, but I don't see the OP wanting the id in neither of the versions of the question

Comment: The regex workes anyway and if you want to match a value in parentheses, you are probably interested in the value too. There's even a name for this, the XY Problem - wanting a solution for problem X, trying Y and when that fails, asking about Y